# Frequent short freezes after upgrade to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, freeze

A problem emerged when I upgraded Kubuntu to 14.04. In several minutes after booting up, Linux starts to freeze shortly (~1 second) and frequently (every ~5 seconds); not only graphics, but also sound and the general workflow. Usually it is starting after I load CPU or network. The same is in Mint 17 "Qiana" (that is based on the same Ubuntu version).

```
CPU: AMD Athlon II X4 631
Motherboard: ASRock A55iCafe
Video: AMD Radeon 6570 (tried both open source and proprietary drivers)
Network: Ralink 802.11n Wireless
```

Comment: If it happens in Ubuntu and Mint, it makes me think it's a hardware problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to be with the kernel time processing: when I run `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i 'unstable'` I see several error messages such as `Clocksource tsc unstable (delta = -3474929768 ns)`.

I solved it by turning on `ACPI HPET table` in BIOS. With another clocksource Linux kernel managed to handle the timers correctly.